# php convert timestamp to xml datetime

Tags: php, xml, datetime, timestamp

In PHP, how do you convert a mysql timestamp like this "1125443836" 
to an xml/date-time like this:

```
   <wp:post_date>2011-01-25 02:10:32</wp:post_date>
```

**UPDATE:**
The columns in the mySQL are stored as int(10).

Based on samples below, this is what I tried with two sample values in my database. 
Something is wrong, maybe hash or Unix dates stored in mySQL table?

```
$testSqlDateStamp = "1125443836";
echo "<BR>DateTest=".date('Y-m-d G:i:s',strtotime($testSqlDateStamp));

$testSqlDateStamp = "1125444107";
echo "<BR>DateTest=".date('Y-m-d G:i:s',strtotime($testSqlDateStamp));
echo "<BR>";
```

Results:

```
 DateTest=1969-12-31 18:00:00
 DateTest=1969-12-31 18:00:00
```

**Second Update: worked without calling strtotime**

```
$testSqlDateStamp = "1125444107";
echo "<BR>DateTest=".date('Y-m-d G:i:s',$testSqlDateStamp);
$testSqlDateStamp = "1125443836";
echo "<BR>DateTest=".date('Y-m-d G:i:s',$testSqlDateStamp);
```

Results:

```
DateTest=2005-08-30 18:21:47
DateTest=2005-08-30 18:17:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date("Y-d-m G-i-s",$time);
```

That should do it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

EDIT: this won't work for mySQL timestamps, they must be converted to unix timestamps via `strtotime()` info: [PHP: strtotime - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: Please see my update, maybe my timestamps are in some odd format?

Comment: Yours worked, got it.. Thanks, I rarely do PHP, just writing a small conversion program.

Answer (score 8):

'Y-m-d G:i:s' is not it. At least not in 2015 (I realize this is old).

In php 5.2.0 the DateTime class has a constant for this:

```
echo 'XML time: ' . date( DateTime::RFC3339, time() ) . '<br>';
```

DateTime::RFC3339 is set to "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo '<wp:post_date>' . date('Y-m-d G:i:s',strtotime($yourMysqlDateStampVar)) . '</wp:post_date>';
```

Comment: Please see my update, maybe my timestamps are in some odd format?